# React Drizzle ContractForm interacting with method with multiple parameters

Tags: reactjs, drizzle

I want to use the React Drizzle contract form to display a form that can take multiple data elements i.e. will display an input box for name and nationality. So this is a simple example that slightly expands on the set and get methods on the drizzle unbox react example which just gets and sets a single variable. Avaiable here https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box

My smart contract is ..

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract PersonContract {

    uint256 public peopleCount = 0;
    mapping(uint => Person) public people;

    struct Person {
        uint256 _id;
        string _firstname;
        string _lastname;
      }

    function addPerson(string memory _firstname, string memory _lastname) public{
        incrementPeopleCount();
        people[peopleCount] = Person(peopleCount, _firstname, _lastname);
    }

    function incrementPeopleCount() internal {
        peopleCount +=1;
    }
}
```

And my React code inside MyComponent is ...

```
  <div className="section">
    <h2>Person Contract</h2>
    <p>
    <ContractData
        drizzle={drizzle}
        drizzleState={drizzleState}
        contract="PersonContract"
        method="Person"
    />
    </p>
    <ContractForm drizzle={drizzle} contract="PersonContractTwo" method="addPerson" />
  </div>
```

When I run this code I get errors for both the ContractData and ContractForm.

For the ContractForm I get ...

```
drizzle-react-components.js:392 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'methods' of undefined
```

and for the ContractForm I get ..

```
index.js:1406 uncaught at initializeDrizzle TypeError: Cannot read property 'abi' of undefined
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the direction of any code examples that involve Drizzle contract forms that involve multiple input elements. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed to compile and deploy the contract.

truffle compile && truffle migrate

will compile and deploy your contract